# Password doesn't store in database UTF-8

Tags: php, sql

I'm having a problem where my password doesn't store after encryption even though it stores perfectly when I don't encrypt it. When I go to the database to check whether it's stored or not, I just see a blank under the `password` column. I want my password's encoding to be UTF-8 (or whatever it's called) since I want to use the Arabic language in my database.

PHP CODE

```
$password = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $_POST['password'], MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
base64_encode($password);
```

Here's a picture that will show you my table's structure :
http://prntscr.com/91nhyx

Comment: No no no, use `password_hash` http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: @cmorrissey Thanks. I will try it. But I still have feeling I'd face the same issue.

Comment: First: passwords should not be stored at all, be it encrypted or not. Instead they should be hashed. Upon authentification that has is compared against a fresh hash of the provided password. That way passwords can never get stolen. 2. If you store a hash, then it is totally irrelevant what encoding you chose, since a hash is build from 7bit characters, so ASCII.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks. But I'm not familiar with hashes. Any link that can help me with it?

Comment: @Nizar Sure! THis is by far the best implementation I have seen for php so far: https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm This is a good intrduction: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: @arkascha Thanks. Even though it was too complex for me. I'm a beginner. Also, I'm just creating a Cryptography project for college.

Comment: @Nizar What exactly are you trying to do for the assignment? Passwords should not be encrypted but hashed instead. Where you told to encrypt the password specifically or something else?

Comment: @AliHamze Sadly, Yeah, I have to encrypt password. I chose PHP. I thought it would be easy.

Comment: @Nizar set your password field to 255 characters. It might be as simple as it getting cut off due to your limit of 70 characters

Comment: @AliHamze OK. I will give it a shot.

Comment: @AliHamze Well, it didn't work. I changed it  from UTF-8 to ASCII, and this is what it looks like : http://prntscr.com/91p3mt

 And this is what the password looks like : http://prntscr.com/91p56p

Comment: @Nizar are you sure you are storing the base64 encoded version? In the code in your question you don't store the base64 anywhere. Should be `$password = base64_encode($password);`

Comment: @AliHamze Thanks XD It works perfect now. You're the man. I can't believe I forgot to store the base64 in the variable.

Comment: @Nizar No problem . I submitted that as an answer so you can accept it and close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the base64 encoded version before storing it in the database:
`$password = base64_encode($password);`

Comment: Now I have another problem... can I contact you privately? like facebook or something?

Comment: Although it would be better if you posted another question, my public Twitter account is on my profile.

Comment: If I post another question, people will be bothered by me. Thinking I'm spamming the website. (I mean two questions in one day?)

Comment: my problem is the decryption. I don't know what's wrong. `   `$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
$check = base64_decode($rows['Password']); 
$check = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $check, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);`

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the value from the database properly? Does the value of `$check` match whats in the database before decoding it?

Comment: Are you using the same `$iv` and `$key` to decrypt that you used to encrypt? If so, yes create a new question with full code.

Comment: OK. I hope you can help then.